# delete duplicate sqlite duplicates using temp table

Tags: sql, sqlite, temp-tables

As you can see below, I'm able to select all the row_numbers that are duplicates. I identified them using a window function ROW_NUMBER()
Although I want to delete them from the database.

How can I change my code to remove the duplicates identified, as I'm currently getting an error

```
WITH RowNumCTE AS (
SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ParcelID,
                     PropertyAddress,
                     SalePrice,
                     SaleDate,
                     LegalReference
                     ORDER BY 
                     UniqueID
                ) row_num

FROM housing_data
)
SELECT * 
FROM RowNumCTE
WHERE row_num > 1
```

- Duplicates are identified as having a row_number greater than 1.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used

```
DELETE FROM housing_data 
WHERE ROWID NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(ROWID) 
  FROM housing_data 
  GROUP BY ParcelID, PropertyAddress, SalePrice, SaleDate, LegalReference
);
```